# Translate Dockerfile from python-alpine to python-slim-buster (debian-based)

Tags: django, docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to improve the Dockerfile we use for deploying a Django-based app at work and first thing I would like to do is change the base image of python from alpine to slim-buster but I have to translate it to a debian-based image. I would like some suggestions on how I could translate it since I have zero to none experience with alpine. This is the original snippet from Docker.

```
FROM python:3.8.6-alpine3.12
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc g++ musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev vim bash nginx supervisor curl && \
    apk add libffi-dev && \
    apk add --update npm && \
    apk add git make cmake
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to

- use `apt-get` instead
- find the equivalents of those packages in the Debian repositories

Some of these will likely be wrong, but you get the gist.

```
FROM python:3.8.6-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    bash \
    build-essential \
    cmake
    curl \
    git \
    libffi-dev \
    libpostgresql-dev \
    make \
    nginx \
    nodejs \
    supervisor \
    vim
```

Comment: How to remove build dependencies? in alpine I could do `apk del build-deps`.

Comment: If you remove build dependencies in a separate step, it doesn't make your image any smaller. These days a multistage build is the thing.

Comment: `apk del` can be called in same RUN step as the ones that installed the dependencies, I am finding a way to do the same with apt

Comment: Well, apt purge and apt autoremove, but building wheels in a separate stage is more efficient.